What was the ultimate purpose of the 25th New Macross-class Colonial Fleet in Macross Frontier?
In the 25 episode 2008 animated series Marcoss Frontier, was it ever established what the ultimate purpose of the 25th New Macross-class Colonial Fleet was?
For example, were they looking for a new planet to colonize, or merely to live nomadically in space so that no single event could wipe out the species.
In which episode is this specified?

Being a called a colonial fleet would imply that their intent was to emigrate to somewhere, to colonize something. Which they did, the Vajra homeworld, in the second movie, Wings of Farewell.

Was that their original planned destination? I don't remember it being mentioned in dialogue as the plan at time of launch.

I don't think any of the fleets had a target. Even the one that found planet Eden.
